# Are stoppped EC2 instances removed from the instance list at some point of time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

If I stop an EC2 instance, for how long will it 'live' in the stoppped state? Is there a limit of days after which AWS removes it from the instances list?
I checked the AWS docs, in particular [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html), but could not find an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

AWS does not delete instances (or any other resource) in a stopped state.  They don't document this but as long as you're paying for the storage of the EBS Volume it's yours forever provided AWS stays in business.

Data may be deleted if an account is closed and they will definitely delete data volumes (all resources) if an account is terminated.  An account is closed 90 days after it is suspended and terminated 150 after suspension.

Technically an EC2 instance will live forever in a stopped state.  It will retain its instance-id and its internal IP address.  As the link you supplied pointed out:

> We don't charge usage for a stopped instance, or data transfer fees, but we do charge for the storage for any Amazon EBS volumes.

As @Swisstone pointed out, here is the lifecycle for an instance [here is the lifecycle for an instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html)

What exists when an instance is stopped is the EBS storage and the Network Interface (ENI).  The instance itself, i.e. the virtual server, no longer exists (excluding bare metal servers).  When the server is started its recreated in a new virtual environment (most likely on completely different hardware) using the storage and ENI.

**References**

[Reactivate Suspended Account](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reactivate-suspended-account/)

Comment: Adding to that, here is the instance lifecycle: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html

Comment: The docs, to my mind, do not explicitly state that the instance will live in the stopped state forever.